# How to turn off code completion in debugging console in pycharm?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

Pycharm code completion is fine in code editor, but rather slow in debugger console. It always hangs for quite a while (up to minutes) after typed in the first letter after a variable of sort (say pandas dataframe).

Is there a way to turn that off in debugger console only? I know it can be turned off completely in settings, but what I want is to turn off in debugger console only, as it works pretty well in code editor.

Comment: I don't see anything in the preferences documentation about this (I don't have PyCharm itself to try it), so I suspect not. You could submit an enhancement request at the jetbrains web site.

Comment: By debugger console, do you mean the 'evaluate expression' window?

Comment: debugger console as in: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-debug-console.html. The `command prompt`  part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an option in [2018.2 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/) to switch variable loading policy to "On-demand". This should fix the console slowness in the first place:

[image]